# How to Remove Automatically Created Legend on an SVM plot

Tags: svm, legend

I have created an SVM Model and have also successfully mapped out the contour lines in R2. See example below where I defined two variables "x" and "y" which will be used to determine the classification of the "indicator" using SVM. The training set is 50% of the original data and the test set is the other 50% of the original data for simplicity.

My issue is with the SVM plot. **I just want to be able to get rid of (or possibly move) the resulting legend which appears to the right of my plot.** It messes with the scaling when I try to plot other points on this plot later on.

```
#simulate the data, x and y are used to predict indicator
x = c(rep(1,10), rep(10,10), rep(20,10))
y = c(rep(2,10), rep(12,10), rep(24,10))
indicator = c(rep("low", 10), rep("med",10), rep("high",10))

df = data.frame(x,y,as.factor(indicator))

# create train and test sets, 50% of data each
set.seed(123)
end = length(df$x)
i = 1:end
train = sample(i, (.5 * end), replace = FALSE)
train = sort(train)
test = setdiff(i,train)

TRAINSET = df[train,]
TESTSET = df[test,]

# use SVM to create a predictive model
svm.model = svm(TRAINSET[,3] ~ ., data = TRAINSET[,c(1,2)], cost = 1000, gamma = .5)

# plot SVM
plot(svm.model, TRAINSET)
```

I can use the legend() function to add legends but I just cannot figure out how to remove one that appears automatically when plotting an SVM model.

Thanks -- I appreciate any help with this!